# CSS have paragraph at the bottom of an element

Tags: css

I am having a CSS issue, I have a div called 'current-property' and inside this div, I have a paragraph. What I am trying to do is what this paragraph at the bottom of the element at all times. Is this possible?

```css
.current-property {
  padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 460px;
}
.current-property p {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.current-property img {
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
}

.current-property h2 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.current-property ul {
    padding-left: 80px;
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.current-property ul li {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="current-property">
  <img src="images/commercial/default-image.png" class="animated" data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-animation-delay="300" />
  <h2>123 Fake Street</h2>
  <div class="property-info">
    <ul>
      <li>Location: Oakland</li>
      <li>Up to 22,000 Sq. Ft.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Call for Availability: 555-555-5555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the HTML supplied, it will be. Can you indicate why it isn't in a demo?

Comment: Hm, even after your edit, IT IS at the bottom... Could you re-formulate your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with positioning. Set the position on the div to relative, and absolute on the paragraph (background color added to visualize the div's space).

```css
.current-property {
  padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  clear: both;
  min-height: 460px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.current-property p {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="current-property">
  <img src="images/commercial/default-image.png" class="animated" data-animation="fadeInLeft" data-animation-delay="300" />
  <h2>123 Fake Street</h2>
  <div class="property-info">
    <ul>
      <li>Location: Oakland</li>
      <li>Up to 22,000 Sq. Ft.</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Call for Availability: 555-555-5555</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand what your question is, you can just add `display:block`to `.property-info p` like this:

```
.property-info p {display:block;}
```

This makes sure that it will take up the full width of the screen, and no elements will `float` or be `inline` to it.

**EDIT**

Add it to the `p` tag

Comment: Divs and paragraphs are block level by default.

Comment: @Paulie_D you're right that's why I changed it to the p tag but I realize that won't work either because it is floated left. He needs to just do text-align-left